# Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Fails it can find my environment files

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an application on the docker platform for elastic beanstalk. it keeps failing. This is the error it gives.

```
2023/09/27 21:12:44.684754 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c docker compose config failed with error exit status 14. Stderr:Failed to load /var/app/staging/mysql.env: open /var/app/staging/mysql.env: no such file or directory
```

Now my mysql file in my docker-compose.yml to my knowledge seems pretty standard and the mysql.env is there in the root with the yml file.

```
 mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_container
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - hubspot-nice
    env_file:
      - mysql.env  #
```

This is my first forey into containerization and I am at a loss on how to even start trouble shooting it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to use Containers - then look at using Amazon Container Service and Fargate - not Elastic Beanstalk.  See - https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/.